# Could not find PROTOBUF Compiler. I have done apt-get install protobuf-compiler

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers, caffe

I have looked at the other question with the same heading and could not solve my problem. I have also done

```
$ sudo apt-get install  libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
$ protoc --version
libprotoc 2.6.1
```

When I do

```
sudo make -j4 && make pycaffe
```

I get

```
CMake Error at cmake/ProtoBuf.cmake:13 (message):
  Could not find PROTOBUF Compiler
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:24 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:46 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/varsha/neuralmap/RRPN/caffe-fast-rcnn/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/varsha/neuralmap/RRPN/caffe-fast-rcnn/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:530: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

@chan3600 suggested that I should remove the build directory. I have no build directory. Please tell me how I can solve this issue.

Comment: clean the cmake cache and cmake again: delete `CMakeCache.txt` and `CMakeFiles` folder.